# Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a visual studio solution with a a vs2010 project
Everytime I open it I got this warning.

> Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in
>   order to enable the project to open in this version and Visual Studio
>   2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior.

ANd it generates some xml log files

I need to definitely convert it to vs 2012

How can I do that without breaking anything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve it by opening the .csproj file and changing this

```
<FileUpgradeFlags>0</FileUpgradeFlags>
```

for this

```
<FileUpgradeFlags></FileUpgradeFlags>
```

Comment: Getting this issue in VS 2017 after doing a migrate to the latest version of the dotnet core CLI and this solution is not relevant there.